# print and count the maximun values in 2d array java

Tags: java

I have 2d array java, I need to look at it and check on the max value, then print it with the count of how many it is in the array

I was trying to do like this but it doesn't work

```js
        int[][] rand = new int[][]{
                {1, 80, 3, 4, 5},
                {13, 199, 80, 8},
                {12, 22, 80, 190}
        };

        int max = rand[0][0];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rand.length; i++){
            for (int ii = 0; ii < rand[i].length; ii++) {
                if (rand[i][ii] > max) {
                    max = rand[i][ii];
                    count++;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(max + " " + count);
```

Comment: You are on the right path but you need to reset the count every time you find a value that is larger. This means you also need an if statement that says if the value is equal to the max then increase count

Comment: So in your code where it says count++ do count=1, and then add an else if statement to increase count when the value is equal to the max

Comment: In addition, you may want to handle empty arrays. The statement `rand[0][0]` will raise an OutOfBoundsException on an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

You are not handling count correctly:

```
int max = rand[0][0];
int count = 0
for (int i = 0; i < rand.length; i++){
    for (int ii = 0; ii < rand[i].length; ii++) {
        if (rand[i][ii] > max) {
            max = rand[i][ii];
            count = 1; // a new maximum's first occurrence
        } else if (rand[i][ii] == max) {
            count++; // another occurrence of the current maximum
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(max + " " + count);
```

- When you find a new maximum, you should reset `count` to 1.
- You should check if the current element is equal to the current maximum, and increment `count` if that's the case.

Output:

```
199 1
```

EDIT:

Fixed the case where the first element is the maximum. It turns out `count` should be initialized to `0` after all, since the loops re-visit the first element, so we don't want to count it twice if it's the maximum.

Comment: It is incorrect sollution. Try it for         int[][] rand = new int[][]{
                {200, 80, 199, 199, 5},
                {13, 199, 80, 8},
                {12, 22, 80, 200}
        };

Comment: @A.Alexander Oh, you are correct. `count` should be initialized to 0 after all.

Comment: @Eran - We posted our answers almost at the same time but when I saw your answer, I didn't even realise that you had done that mistake and in the honour of a great as you, I deleted my answer which didn't have this mistake .

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams:

```
    int max = Arrays.stream(rand)
            .mapToInt(row -> Arrays.stream(row).max().getAsInt())
            .max().getAsInt();

    int count = Arrays.stream(rand)
            .mapToInt(row -> (int) Arrays.stream(row).filter(i-> i==max).count())
            .reduce(Integer::sum).getAsInt();
```